# git fast-import doesn't work

Tags: git, git-fast-import

I just try to delete the history behind a specific commit. I found at [Git: how to remove history before a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459209/git-how-to-remove-history-before-a-specific-commit) the following command:

```
git fast-export master~5..master | (cd ../newrepo.git && git init . && git fast-import && git checkout)
```

I just changed the command for my case (i need the last 65 commits of the branch ip6_dev):

```
git fast-export ip6_dev~65..ip6_dev | (cd ../puppet/ && git init . && git fast-import && git checkout)
```

When I run the command i get the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Alloc'd objects:      10000
Total objects:         7985 (       782 duplicates                  )
      blobs  :         4978 (         0 duplicates       2304 deltas of       49
25 attempts)
      trees  :         2942 (       782 duplicates        263 deltas of       29
28 attempts)
      commits:           65 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of
 0 attempts)
      tags   :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of
 0 attempts)
Total branches:           1 (         1 loads     )
      marks:        1048576 (      5043 unique    )
      atoms:           2438
Memory total:          2997 KiB
       pools:          2606 KiB
     objects:           390 KiB
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pack_report: getpagesize()            =      65536
pack_report: core.packedGitWindowSize =   33554432
pack_report: core.packedGitLimit      =  268435456
pack_report: pack_used_ctr            =        358
pack_report: pack_mmap_calls          =         65
pack_report: pack_open_windows        =          1 /          1
pack_report: pack_mapped              =   14669749 /   14669749
---------------------------------------------------------------------

fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

What am i missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [You are on a branch yet to be born](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001587/you-are-on-a-branch-yet-to-be-born)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very last step of your `&& ...` sequence is:

```
git checkout
```

Note the lack of a branch name (or specific commit ID or paths).  Then take a look at [the `git checkout` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) (which I admit makes this a bit obscure):

> Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or the specified tree. If no paths are given, *git checkout* will also update `HEAD` to set the specified branch as the current branch. [...] You could omit <branch>, in which case the command degenerates to "check out the current branch" ...

Hence, the next question to ask is: "what is the name of the current branch?"  Normally one might run `git branch` to find out, but if we do that we might get *nothing at all* (you won't get nothing at all, but you won't get a branch marked with an asterisk either; see below):

```
$ mkdir example.git
$ cd example.git
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ git branch
$
```

There's an alternative lower-level git command that gives us the right answer:

```
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
master
$
```

(or we can cheat and look at the file `.git/HEAD`).

Note that I haven't actually run `git fast-import` at this point, but if I run `git checkout` with no arguments, I get the same error:

```
$ git checkout
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

The only remaining thing, then, is to point out that `git fast-import` will import commits (and branches) as directed by its input, which came from `git fast-export`, which you directed—by name—to export only certain commits from branch `ip6_dev`.  Hence, I can predict that if *you* run `git branch` you'll see:

```
$ git branch
  ip_dev
$
```

This means your new repo has only the one branch, `ip_dev`, which is *not* the branch you're on: you're on `master`, which does not yet exist.  Had you `fast-export`ed some commit(s) on branch `master`, `master` *would* exist and you'd be able to do `git checkout`.

If you want to have just the one `ip_dev` branch, simply check that out explicitly, so that you switch the current branch.  You will still have no `master`, but now git won't complain about being unable to check it out.